# How to make pulseaudio and ubuntu detect the same audio device as alsa driver

Tags: gnome, pulseaudio, alsa

I use Ubuntu 14.04 x64 and I use gnome-shell on my laptop. I have a Bose companion 5 (which is basically a USB sound system) and a HDMI port, both does work perfectly when I just boot with the cable plugin.

However, when my laptop go to sleep or get unplugged from those two outputs, if I plug back the device, I end up without any hardware detection (only the built-in speakers) from pulse and gnome-shell sound output selector while if I use alsamixer, the device look up and ready.

`gstreamer-properties` allow me to select and test effectively any device but while `alsa` recognize any device on the run, `pulse` is not capable of handling things correctly, my question is then:

How can I make pulse detect and use the same hardware as alsa, or how to remove completely and gracefully pulseaudio (meaning volume applet running in gnome shell)
I don't mind if the project implies to recompile half gnome shell if it implies those audio outputs work all the time.

Pulse does not list my soundcard when I use command `pactl list cards` while the module plug&play for sound card is loaded in `pactl list modules`.  I really don't know what to do, the behavior seems pretty random.

Comment: I recommend you reporting a bug. That device should work even after suspension/hibernation. If it doesn't then something is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the command line:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

finally worked on a clean ubuntu 14.04 up to date install.